# displaying Google Maps API v2 on real device/emulator. can't figure out error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2

i am in the process of creating a app which track the user location using Google maps and calculate the distance. i have not calculate the distance but is trying to create a map but faced problems. i know using Google Maps API v2 cannot run on a emulator as it does not support Google Play Services. i have tried running on emulator and my real phone but both faced problems

On emulator:
i saw that the person who posted this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc can do it so i think it is possible, but it does not say how to do it.

i followed all the steps in this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUsBOZ7-qBE and downloaded all apk uses the same emulator. but there is the error that my google play services need updating. i researched and it means google play services is not supported on emulator..

On real devices:
when i run my application, it crashes by saying "Unfortunately, My ApplicationNameApp has stopped" then i press ok. the CatLog is 
EDIT:

```
01-26 01:33:08.004: D/dalvikvm(10815): GC_CONCURRENT freed 205K, 6% free 12413K/13191K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 19ms
01-26 01:33:08.004: D/dalvikvm(10815): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 11ms
01-26 01:33:08.049: D/AndroidRuntime(10815): Shutting down VM
01-26 01:33:08.049: W/dalvikvm(10815): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x4178f2a0)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.studenthealthapp/com.example.studenthealthapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.example.studenthealthapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    ... 11 more
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at maps.af.ch.a(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at maps.af.al.a(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at maps.af.bg.a(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at maps.af.bf.a(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at ebt.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
01-26 01:33:08.054: E/AndroidRuntime(10815):    ... 21 more
01-26 01:33:08.074: D/dalvikvm(10815): GC_CONCURRENT freed 248K, 7% free 12656K/13511K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 23ms
```

however, when i run my previous separate project where it just contain gps and calculate distance(inaccurate though), it can work and display with no problem. it does display my current location but i never feed any location data through emulator so i think it worked. emulator has no real-time gps as far as i know. if anyone knows you can tell me too.

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/displayMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Android Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.studenthealthapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission android:name="com.example.studenthealthapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.studenthealthapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.studenthealthapp.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.studenthealthapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API key value"/>
      <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</application>
```

My Main Java file

```
package com.example.studenthealthapp;

//import android.R;
import com.example.studenthealthapp.R; 
//import com.example.studenthealthtools.MainActivity;
//import com.example.studenthealthtools.MainActivity;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;
//import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

private GoogleMap googleMap;
private boolean resultStatus;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(isGooglePlay())
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if(googleMap == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Getting map",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        googleMap =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayMap)).getMap();

        if(googleMap != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

}

private void setUpMap() 
{
    //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    //Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if(provider == null)
    {
        onProviderDisabled(provider);
    }
    //set map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    //Get current location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(myLocation != null)
    {
        onLocationChanged(myLocation);
    }


}

private boolean isGooglePlay() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services is available",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10).show();

    }
    return (false);

 }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
    //Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    //Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

    //Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Show the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    //Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

i have seem many tutorial and i believe i have done all the necessary steps(except maybe one that caused this error?) download google play services, import google play services. import support play libarary as my app support API below 11. generate the API key..target build correct version i believe

i know normally we must use real phone but as i work in a team, what if my teammates uses emulator while i uses real phone to present to my client? my deadline is very close now, any help would be appreciated. thanks

EDIT:i can display my map.
[image: screenshot of my application]

does the red thing means where i am? but it should display "you are here" text and it did not. also, it is inaccurate as my exact location should be further to the up left though the environment is correct. in one of the block... what does the blue means. sometimes it turn to a arrow which change directions or the light blue color around the blue dot change size if i'm not wrong

Comment: first of all use bluestacks to run your app as an emulator

Comment: second , filter LogCat and show errors only when the crash occurs

Comment: I think, you have not pasted the full crash log, it looks incomplete.

Comment: @fadt taher, i have install bluestacks before but how do i connect it to eclipse and run as my emulator?

Comment: updated the LogCat. as i said, just now the message dissapear after it appears very fast so i can't copied it in time. i am a newbie at doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues:

1) The logcat says you are missing:

```
<uses-permissionandroid:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Do not change the package name to yours.

2) These permission are not longer required.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.studenthealthapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<permission android:name="com.example.studenthealthapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

3) Please do not share your API key with the world.